# Yielding generator data in batches while reading files from disk is piling up in memory just like loading whole data

Tags: python, keras, generator

I am using keras to train my Inception-Resnet for my MRI data. The data is spread across 151 files and each file corresponds to a patient (I cannot accumulate data into one as filenames are IDs for paitent which provide labels). The data is too large to fit in my memory (larger than 25 GB). So I used **keras.fit_generator**. I am trying to read files (equal in number to batch_size) and do some processing on them and then yield that data and repeat. The problem here is that when I use generator and observe my RAM at every next(data), my RAM usage increases every time instead of remaining same or almost same (as file sizes are nearly same) which at some 88 files crashes my code. What am I missing? I've tried a lot. Here is my generator code:

```
def file_reading(datafiles, batch_size, labels, d_type, N):

  while True:
    batch_data = []
    batch_label = []
    batch_start = 0
    batch_end = batch_size
    label = -1
    i=0

    while (batch_end<=N):
      for path in datafiles[batch_start:batch_end] :
        id = int(path.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0].lstrip("0"))
        if id in labels:
          dlabel_of_id = labels[id][d_type]
        else:
          pass
        if (dlabel_of_id != 'na'):
          if (dlabel_of_id == 'yes'):
            label = 1
          elif (dlabel_of_id == 'no'):
            label = 0
          raw = mne.io.read_raw_edf(path, preload=True);
          if max(raw.times) < 660:
            raw.crop(tmin=60, tmax=max(raw.times));
          else:
            raw.crop(tmin=60, tmax=660);
          temp = montages(raw)
          raw = 0
          temp = np.resize(temp,(2966,2966,3))
          batch_data.append(temp)
          batch_label.append(label)
      yield (batch_data, batch_label)
      batch_start += batch_size
      batch_end += batch_size
```

Moreover, when I do this

```
data = file_reading(paths, 16, labels, 'EEG', 151)
len(next(data)[0])
```

Then the memory does not pile up and generator works fine.

Comment: Not familiar with the module, but I wonder if the results of  `mne.io.read_raw_edf` are persisting when you remove the reference (`raw = 0`) due to having passed it to `montages`?

Comment: I don't see you ever reseting your `batch_data` or `batch_label` lists, so each batch after the first is going to include the first values in the list along with the values from the new batch. You may want the lists to be created inside the `while` loop, before the `for` loop.

Comment: @Blckknght yes, that was the lacking in code, which somehow got removed while clearing out comments.